# Maps api does not return airport type. Instead it returns establishment

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey I am making a request to fetch places by making an HTTP request to

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=airport&key=MY_KEY
```

The response contains airport objects with types equal to establishment. When fetching the single object from the api by:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ2a3dh2ZeWxMRe2Cc31AcWic&key=MY_KEY
```

I get a richer types array:

```
types: [
  "airport",
  "point_of_interest",
  "establishment"
],
```

However, that requires me to load the object in order to check for the airport type.
How can I get the all types with first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3) the `airport` type is not supported for *Autocomplete requests*, but:

> `establishment` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return
>   only business results.

You probably want to consume [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) instead where `airport` type is supported (follow [this link](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1) for a more details)

**Example**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=39.601944,19.912222&radius=5000&types=airport&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```